# I need to print the percentage of votes to the nearest tenth decimal place. ( ie 60.0) It only prints the whole number. Below is my code and output

Tags: php

Total number of votes is 5
Daddy Yankee has 3 has ( 60% of total )
J Alvarez has 1 has ( 20% of total )
Yandel has 1 has ( 20% of total )

```
<?php

    $totalvotes = "SELECT SUM(votes) AS total FROM voting";


    $totalvotesresults = mysql_query( $totalvotes )
    or die( "Could not get total votes " .mysql_error() );



    $data = mysql_fetch_object( $totalvotesresults );
    echo "<div>Total number of votes is ". $data->total ."</div>\n";


    $total = $data->total;



    $artistandvotes = "SELECT * FROM voting";


    $artistnandvotesresults = mysql_query( $artistandvotes )
    or die( "Could not get artist names and votes " .mysql_error() );



    for( $i = 0; $i < mysql_numrows( $artistnandvotesresults ); $i++ ) {




    $data = mysql_fetch_array( $artistnandvotesresults  );
    echo "<div>". $data['artist'] ." has ". $data['votes'] .  " has ( ". $data['votes']/$total*100 ."% of total )</div>\n";


    } // ends for loop


    ?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php, `sprintf`

Comment: number_format(), sprintf(), round()... check these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `number_format` to print to a fixed number of decimal places.